# Elegant Way to Put Array of Values Into CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, nsarray, core-location

Is there an elegant way to create a CLLocationCoordinate2D object from an array of NSDecimalNumber values?  Perhaps a recursive function?

I'm new to objective C and am having difficulty with this.

Below is an example of the data structures I'm working with.

---

an array of NSDecimalNumber values:

```
NSLog(@"path: %@", [path description]);
```

returns

```
path: (
    "-71.4826609644423",
    "27.7231737704478",
    "-71.4826608497223",
    "27.7231120144099",
    "-71.4826391681679",
    "27.7228678610506",
    ...
    "-71.482414263977",
    "27.7225217655116",
)
```

---

I can manually create the CLLocationCoordinate2D object like this:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D pathCoords[5]={
    CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(27.7231737704478,-71.4826609644423),
    CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(27.7231120144099,-71.4826608497223),
    CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(27.7228678610506,-71.4826391681679),
    ...
    CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(27.7225217655116,-71.482414263977),
};
```

Any coding suggestions are welcome.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you have already created a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` structure called `pathCoords` of size 5.

```
for(int i=0;i<[path count]/2;i++)
   pathCoords[i] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([path objectAtIndex:2*i+1], [path objectAtIndex:2*i]);
```

The nature of your problem is not recursive, so if you go recursive - it's an overkill.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!
The compiler is returning an error for `[path objectAtIndex:2*i+1]`:
`Passing 'id' to parameter of incompatible type 'CLLocationDegrees' (aka 'double')`

Comment: Well, you need to cast types properly. I just typed the code on-the-fly. You need to convert NSDecimalNumber into a double. This (https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=nsdecimalnumber+to+double) will help.

Answer (score 0):

The final solution including typecasting the NSDecimalNumbers to doubleValues:

```
for(int i=0; i<[path count]/2; i++) {
        pathCoords[i] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[path objectAtIndex:2*i+1] doubleValue], [[path objectAtIndex:2*i] doubleValue]);
```